# KKT system with rank-deficient constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have an optimization problem of the following form:
$$
    \begin{aligned}
        \operatorname*{minimize}_x & \quad \frac{1}{2}||x - a||^2 \\
        \operatorname{subject~to}  & \quad D^Tx = b
    \end{aligned}
$$
I attempted to solve it, but I get results which do not satisfy the constraints. I am going to show how I solved it, and would like to ask your help in finding what is wrong.

The resulting KKT system is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x + D \lambda = a \\
&D^T x         = b
\end{aligned}
$$

In my case, the matrix $D$ is *rank-deficient*, *huge*, and I do not directly represent it. Instead, I have functions which can efficiently compute $Dz$ and $D^T z$. In addition, I can quickly compute $(D^T D)^\dagger z$  ($\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse) using a very fast algorithm.

Using the first equation I get:
$$ x = a - D \lambda $$
I substitute this $x$ into the second equation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(D^T D) \lambda  = D^T a - b
\end{aligned}
$$
Now I solve the system above by using my algorithm to compute $\lambda = (D^T D)^\dagger (D^T a - b)$. After computing $\lambda$ I can compute $x = a - D \lambda$.

As stated at the beginning, I am getting $x$ which does not satisfy the constraints, and I would like to know why. What am I missing?

---

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, there might be no solution to the system of constraints due to rank-deficiency. However, I found a way to construct vectors $b$ such that it will not happen. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: My original problem statement is wrong. I will correct it. The KKT conditions are correct :)

Comment: $(D^T D)(D^T D)^\dagger$ is not the identity in general.

Comment: also, if $D$ has rank deficit, there might be no $x$ with $D^T x = b$.

Comment: Pseudoinverse gives you an *approximate* solution. Use better Gauss elimination, it is fast. Note that $b\in\text{im}D^T$ is a necessary condition for the constraint to be non-empty.

Comment: I cannot use Gaussian Elimination, since I do not represent the matrix $D$. I wrote explicitly the only operations which I can perform efficiently. But I will elaborate more, since it might help.

Comment: @user251257, this might indeed be the problem I will check it.